# Shape color value display without pressing play button

Tags: excel, vba

How could I get the total number of shapes I have in an excel sheet with same color without click run sub play button and the value will automatically show?

Example: I have 3 yellow color shapes, 2 orange color shapes, and 1 blue color shape and I wish to get the result as sheet2 Cell(5,3): 3 (yellow color) Cell(5,4): 2 (orange color) Cell(5,5): 1 (blue color). But when vbaproject password protected or code was hided, the run sub play button will no function.

Code as below:

```
Private Sub Ignore_Click()
    Dim sh As Sheet2
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim shprange As ShapeRange
    Dim CountyellowShape As Long
    Dim CountorangeShape As Long
    Dim CountblueShape As Long

    Sheet2.Cells(5, 3).Resize().ClearContents
    Sheet2.Cells(5, 4).Resize().ClearContents
    Sheet2.Cells(5, 5).Resize().ClearContents
    Sheet2.Shapes.SelectAll

    For Each shp In Sheet1.Shapes

        If shp.Type = msoGroup Then
            Set shprange = shp.Ungroup
            Set oMyGroup = shprange.Group

            If shprange.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0) Then CountChildShapeYELLOW = CountChildShapeYELLOW + 1
            If shprange.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(247, 150, 70) Then CountChildShapeORANGE = CountChildShapeORANGE + 1
            If shprange.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 176, 240) Then CountChildShapeBLUE = CountChildShapeBLUE + 1

        End If
    Next shp

    For Each shp In Sheet1.Shapes
        If shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0) Then CountShapeYELLOW = CountShapeYELLOW + 1
        If shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(247, 150, 70) Then CountShapeORANGE = CountShapeORANGE + 1
        If shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 176, 240) Then CountShapeBLUE = CountShapeBLUE + 1
    Next shp

    Sheet2.Cells(5, 3) = CountShapeYELLOW + CountChildShapeYELLOW
    Sheet2.Cells(5, 4) = CountShapeORANGE + CountChildShapeORANGE
    Sheet2.Cells(5, 5) = CountShapeBLUE + CountChildShapeBLUE

    End Sub
```

Comment: You could run your macro on the `Worksheet_Activate` event and again, if necessary, when one of the shapes is modified.

Comment: Thank you for your reply,  would you mind to show me? I am a newbie in Excel VBA...

Comment: Hi Variatus, thank you for you helping, I try to change Ignore_Click to Worksheet_Activate, its work, thank you so much!!!

Comment: I'm glad my suggestion helped you. Please remember to mark the answer as "Accepted"